# Free Data recovery tool for linux?

Tags: linux, file-recovery

I deleted files on my linux drive that I shouldn't have. What is a good tool to use to recover these files that will:

- Recover the various file types (txt, php etc)
- Recover it as the original files names

TestDisk and PhotoRec almost do the trick, but the original filenames are not restored. So I need a better solution?

Comment: Any of those helpful? http://superuser.com/questions/98183/recovering-a-accidently-deleted-file-in-ubuntu

Comment: What file system?  There are many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec - Tested by myself, it works great.

Comment: I once used GNU ddrescue to pull lots of data off a damaged hard drive using Puppy Linux. It did pretty well. I did have to download some development tools for Puppy, though, so I could compile it.

Comment: The problem with PhotoRec is that it doesnt recover the actual file NAMES. Any suggestions on how to get the fileNames?

Comment: It could be hard because of the way how file system works. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode: "Inodes do not contain file names, only file metadata.
Unix directories are lists of "link" structures, each of which contains one filename and one inode number."

Answer (score 1):

This may depend on the file system you are using. For example, on ext2, you can use [undelete](http://www.stud.tu-ilmenau.de/~mojo/undelete.html) utility.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not helpful to the OP, but the correct mantra here is "restore from backup."

If you haven't set up a fake delete (that moves files to a trashcan for later deletion), most of the Linux filesystems offer at best a probability of recovery.

Comment: Unfortunately - at least in my case - it was in the process of moving files from my camera's media stick to my file server that things went wrong.  The file server is backed up nightly by Bacula - haven't yet found a camera that will do that!!