# Disk formatting issue on Linux

Tags: linux, data-recovery, ubuntu-10.10, ext4, hard-drive-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free Data recovery tool for linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/100298/free-data-recovery-tool-for-linux)

my dad formatted a 204GB disk and it's now showing as "Unknown" 199GB partition with 4.7GB extended partition and 4.7GB swap space (witch is how it used to look only with the "Unknown" being replaced with ext4 when looking at it through the built in disk utility), He also stated that it was done with the live install CD. So the data may have been overwritten. but he has told me He cancelled at the beginning of the formatting process so I think he corrupted the partition... or fully formatted it but im not 100% on what he has done. 
it is not the OS drive only one for storing other data like videos+ images+ installers ect. And also the OS disk is the 32bit version

Can I restore it and recover the data or is there a free tool I can run to recover the old partition and files  or are they simply lost?

If I can recover it all from this early stage, can you please walk me through how to go about recovering the data as I am a new user of Linux and its OS (Ubuntu 10.10)

Comment: Linux 9.04? What? I don't think there's a Linux version that high yet...

Comment: Probably Ubuntu

Comment: @user81686 Did I correctly understand you were using `dd` to format the disk?

Comment: no he used the live CD so I would be thinking its just the standard

Comment: I think you're doomed. You might want to post the actual dd command you used, but in essence it's time to restore from backup.

Comment: @CarlF Maybe he didn't use `dd`, it's not too clear from the post (although it contained `DD` first), but then why would anybody use this as "the standard to format" something?

Comment: to go back to basics it would be the standard formatting tool on the live CD. and also I meant to type HDD not "DD" (I hit the h key but to softly for my keyboard to type ha ha... sorry about the mistake)

Comment: thanks for the feedback and still constructing my question more around the info I was given about this system >.< sorry it is poorly asked as I know little more then this about how it used to be set up and about the cause of this then I have already stated this drive was just for holding data not the actual OS

Answer (score 0):

You can try [photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to recover the files and [supergrub](http://www.bootproblems.com/) for the partition but without knowing exactly what you did it's going to be very difficult for people here to help you.

Comment: i take it i should run through supergrub first then photorec?