# How do I empty the trash (or restore items from trash can) in Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

I have been deleting items for the past few months and I guess the trash can must be eating up a lot of space by now. Yet, even though its easy to 'move to the deleted items folder', I have not as yet seen a menu item or any instructions that shows how to either:

1. empty the trash can
2. restore previously deleted items

Searching on google did not return any useful results either - surely, someone must now how to do this?

Comment: This might be a better question for superuser.com.  This will help a bit for recovery of deleted files: http://superuser.com/questions/98183/recovering-a-accidently-deleted-file-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

There should be an icon in the bottom right I think for the Trash, which you can view and from there empty.

Entering: `trash:///` into nautilus' address bar will also get you there.