# Undelete a deleted file Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recovering a accidently deleted file in Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/98183/recovering-a-accidently-deleted-file-in-ubuntu)

I deleted a file (move to trash, then empty trash) that it turns out I need :(.  Is there a way to get it back?

Comment: Dupe of [Recovering a accidently deleted file in Ubuntu](http://superuser.com/questions/98183/recovering-a-accidently-deleted-file-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Ah, yep.  All my searching was for "undelete" not "recover"  Thanks!